# How Can I Display Multiple Images in HTM file?

Tags: c#, html, image

I know how to display multiple images, but I mean for the method that I'm using which I will show.  I have a project that I select a camera from a dropdownlist and then will go to a new page and display the image.  But now I want to put all 4 cameras on a page, but the way I'm doing I only know how to display one image.

Here is my current code: Image handler

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace MultiImagesImageHandler
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ImgHandler
/// </summary>
public class ImgHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    static public string filename { get; set; }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string saveTo = filename;
        FileStream writeStream1 = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        string loadFrom = filename;
        using (FileStream fs1 = File.Open(loadFrom, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            ReadWriteStream(fs1, writeStream1);
        }
        byte[] tt = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/"+filename));
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(tt);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // readStream is the stream you need to read
    // writeStream is the stream you want to write to
    private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }
}
}
```

The code for HTM file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Image 1</title>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function refreshIt() {
        if (!document.images) return;
        document.getElementById("imgcontainer2").src = "/ImgHandler.ashx?" + Math.random();
        setTimeout('refreshIt()', 700);
    }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload=" setTimeout('refreshIt()',700)">
 <img id="imgcontainer2" src="/ImgHandler.ashx" alt="cam image2"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I can't think of how I can change it to display more than the one image.  If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.  And if more info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: You could add a parameter to your request with the camera id such as `/ImgHandler.ashx?camera=1`, and then handle that number within ProcessRequest to show different images for different ids.

Comment: html is not really my strong suit, would I put that in <img id= part or in the java function? or both?

Comment: Try adding `<img src="/ImgHandler.ashx?camera=2/>"` to your page and have a look at `context.Request.QueryString["camera"]` in ProcessRequest.

Comment: Will I have to change the java function or have a function for each image?